# The usage of "where"

Tags: word-usage, american-english, british-english

Is it OK to use "where" for explaining non-physical place?
For instance, is it OK to say "It is a social network ***where*** users can ..."?

Comment: That sentence is fine and *where* is talking about the place - *social network*. So the antecedent is *social network*.

Comment: @Man_From_India: Indeed. Obviously something like a "social network" doesn't meaningfully "exist" in any particular ***place** (= physical location)* anyway. But we routinely use "spatial" metaphoric terms to reference such contexts.

Comment: Thanks, @FumbleFingers - Such as what?

Comment: @Alireza Ghaffari: Such as ELL itself, ***where*** we use English much the same as anyone else, but we're not collectively in any particular physical location. Or an even more abstract "location" such as quantum mechanics, *where* they also use figurative language in exactly same way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that sounds perfectly normal. In this context, 'where' could be swapped with 'in which'.

'In which' is often used to describe contextual details:

> I had a dream in which I was a superhero.